# Where does this socket supposed to go?

Tags: vw, air-intake, tiguan

I have recently bought a used 2022 Tiguan, SE. the check engine light was on (p0491 - insufficient air flow bank 1) so when trying to check the air pump I found this socket dangling alone near the air pump, so where does it go? Is it related somehow to the air pump?

It's also worth mentioning that I found the fuse related to the air pump broken, and when short circuitting it I didn't hear any noise coming from the air pump.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This is not meant to be a judgement on you or anything, but would need to say from what I see in the engine compartment, this vehicle has been ridden hard and put away wet ... meaning, it looks like it's had a hard life. I would expect an engine compartment to look like this after it's 10+ years old, not barely two years old it being a 2022.

Comment: A Google search for Tiguan SE P0491 will give you many answers. It will be up to you to find service manuals, subscribe to Alldata.diy or Mitchell for online service manuals if answers aren't given here. The air pump usually runs at engine startup for a few minutes to help the catalytic converter get up to operating temperature for emissions efficiency then shuts down. Blower, plumbing, clogged piping and damaged wiring are some things to consider, including where that two wire connector goes to. Air pump, air temperature sensor?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I suspect the car was flooded and a salvage. Otherwise, this would all be under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a socket for a small light bulb for the side of the vehicle, either a blinker or marker.

[image]